# Applying Gradle plugin from local file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have the following gradle plugin that does the job of starting up a java process. The code for this lives under a file named `startAppServerPlugin.gradle` under the project's buildSrc directory.

The code of the plugin looks like this:

```
    repositories.jcenter()
    dependencies {
        localGroovy()
        gradleApi()
    }
}

public class StartAppServer implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('startServer', type: StartServerTask)
    }
}

public class StartServerTask extends DefaultTask {

    String command
    String ready
    String directory = '.'

    StartServerTask(){
        description = "Spawn a new server process in the background."
    }

    @TaskAction
    void spawn(){
        if(!(command && ready)) {
            throw new GradleException("Ensure that mandatory fields command and ready are set.")
        }

        Process process = buildProcess(directory, command)
        waitFor(process)
    }

    private waitFor(Process process) {
        def line
        def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.quiet line
            if (line.contains(ready)) {
                logger.quiet "$command is ready."
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private static Process buildProcess(String directory, String command) {
        def builder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(' '))
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true)
        builder.directory(new File(directory))
        def process = builder.start()
        process
    }

}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way of having this imported into my main `build.gradle` file due everything I tried so far has been unsuccessful.

So far I have tried this:

```
apply from: 'startAppServerPlugin.gradle'
apply plugin: 'fts.gradle.plugins'
```

But it has been failing. I've tried searching online for examples of doing what I need to do but so far I've been unsuccessful. Can anyone please provide a hint as to how I'm supposed to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path. The first order of business is to import the external gradle build using:

```
apply from: 'startAppServerPlugin.gradle'
```

Then you can apply the plugin with:

```
apply plugin: StartAppServer
```

---

*See [Script Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins) and [Applying Binary Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_binary_plugins)*

Answer (score 1):

The buildSrc folder is treated as an included build, where the code is compiled and put on the classpath of the surrounding project. The actual `build.gradle` file in buildSrc is only used for compiling that project, and the things you put in it will not be available elsewhere.

You are supposed to create your classes as a normal Java/Groovy/Kotlin project under buildSrc. I don't know if you can use the default package, but it is generally best practice to have a package name anyway.

For example, your `StartAppServer` plugin should be in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/my/package/StartAppServer.groovy`. Then you can apply it in your build scripts with `apply plugin: my.package.StartAppServer`.

There are a lot of good examples in the [user guide](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-plugins/).

Answer (score 0):

inside the `startAppServerPlugin.gradle` script you can call

```
    apply plugin: StartAppServer
```